# By click on attachment button url will be copied in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, attachment

[all other social connectivity icons working with functioanlity, i am facing problem with "COPY" icon, when i click it goes to blank page, it should work the URL to copy

copy icon is not default action come with wordpress share addon, i am added customly

please help][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoCbP.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the effect using javascript only.
Look to this post [Copy to clipboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)